# Check if List of Matrix Indexes are adjacent

Tags: matrix, prolog, geometry, logic

Given a list of indexes List and the matrix size N, I want to check if indexes of that list are contiguous.

For example, matrix 5x5, the indexes are as it follows:

```
 1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25


isContiguous([11,12,13,7,2], 5) :- yes.

isContiguous([14,15,16,17,18], 5) :- no.
```

I tried to implement a depth first search, starting with the first index and checking if the following is contiguous, but I couldn't, as it only works if the list makes a line or a column and the first element is in the beginning or in the end of that shape.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: No, DFS works for branched structures too - after finishing of one branch search returns to earlier nodes to continue.

Comment: How is this related to geometry?

Comment: @GuyCoder Sorry, and thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define a relation for a node adjacencies and a procedure to see if there is a single connected graph between your nodes:

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

adjacent(Size, N, _, Adj):-
  Adj #= N-Size,
  Adj #> 0.
adjacent(Size, N, Max, Adj):-
  Adj #= N+Size,
  Adj #=< Max.
adjacent(Size, N, _, Adj):-
  0 #\= N mod Size,
  Adj #= N+1.
adjacent(Size, N, _, Adj):-
  1 #\= N mod Size,
  Adj #= N-1.

is_contiguous(L, Size):-
  Max #= Size*Size,
  between(1, Max, Len), % sanity checks for when L is not instantiated
  length(L, Len),
  select(N, L, L1),
  between(1, Max, N),   % idem
  is_contiguous1([N], L1, Size, Max).

is_contiguous1(_, [], _, _).
is_contiguous1(Seen, Rem, Size, Max):-
  member(N, Seen),
  adjacent(Size, N, Max, Adj),
  \+(member(Adj, Seen)),
  select(Adj, Rem, NRem),
  is_contiguous1([Adj|Seen], NRem, Size, Max).
```

Sample run:

```
?- is_contiguous([11,12,13,7,2], 5).
true.
?- is_contiguous([14,15,16,17,18], 5).
false.
?- once(is_contiguous([14,15,X,16,17,18], 5)).
X = 19
```

Comment: I think your third example is wrong, because 15 is adjacent to 19 but 16 is not adjacent to 19. I actually liked your answer better until I checked the third example.

Comment: My solution checks whether there is only one connected graph for the input nodes. The order of the nodes does not matter. If the problem was to find a path a simple DFS would solve it